# IBM QISKit local simulator error, can't find gcc

Tags: python, xcode, macos, gcc, qiskit

When I want to run the Bell example code from qiskit.org in macOS terminal it throws this error:

```
ERROR:qiskit.backends.local.qasm_simulator_cpp:ERROR: Simulator encountered a runtime error: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/7/libgomp.1.dylib
```

Python3 works well and I have Xcode installation but the gcc is not there (I found it in /usr/bin). What can I do?

Comment: If I type brew install gcc it installs gcc 8 and if I type brew install gcc@7 there is no /usr/local/opt/gcc/7 just 8 and the v7 is in /usr/local/opt/gcc@7. I tried to link it but its not helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your current installation

pip uninstall qiskit

Then install 0.5.3

pip install qiskit

Should work out of the box. I ran into this same issue with 0.5. Test with a default program

https://github.com/QISKit/qiskit-sdk-py#creating-your-first-quantum-program